# Login to netlify from your workspace terminal

Tags: npm

I used `netlify login` in the terminal but it gives the error -
`netlify: command not found`.
I have also installed netlify CLI using this command -
`npm install netlify-cli -g` but still getting this error.

```
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/rollup/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/traffic-mesh-agent-darwin-x64@^0.27.10 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/traffic-mesh-agent/node_modules/@netlify/traffic-mesh-agent-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/traffic-mesh-agent-darwin-x64@0.27.10: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/traffic-mesh-agent-win32-x64@^0.27.10 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/traffic-mesh-agent/node_modules/@netlify/traffic-mesh-agent-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/traffic-mesh-agent-win32-x64@0.27.10: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @octokit/plugin-request-log@1.0.2 requires a peer of @octokit/core@>=3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rudrakshi/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T05_32_03_765Z-debug.log
rudrakshi@rudrakshi-pc:~$ netlify
netlify: command not found
rudrakshi@rudrakshi-pc:~$ npm install http-server -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rudrakshi/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T05_34_54_847Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I used ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command works fine on ubuntu 20.04 - `sudo npm i -g netlify-cli`.
`